# Slow PDF upload for Confluence

Tags: pdf, upload, jpeg, gif, confluence

We run a site that we host that uses the Atlassian Confluence.  The site works great and is being used now.  But there is one thing.

It seems like when pdf and gifs are uploaded the upload speed will be slower.  But the smaller files will upload fine.  Has anyone else having an issue with uploading pdf's into confluence?

I am trying to use fiddler to track the speed but am not having luck with that.  Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of Confluence such as 3.1 and up you can drag and drop multiple files onto a Confluence page.

For this to work you have to be using a browser which supports "Google Gears".

Using drag-n-drop gives you nice progress bars so you can see the upload progress real time. Also doing this uses the WebDAV protocal to upload files which can be much faster than sending via the standard HTTP upload.

The upload speed should be the same, however if you are rendering large PDFs in a Confluence page it can slow things down especially on the initial render. We HAVE encountered issues rendering very large PDFs which can sometimes *feel* like the upload speed is being impacted, but it is actually the in-page-rendering which is slow on the first page load of that PDF.

More info about drag and drop here:
http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Drag-and-Drop